# What is the best way to write a cron job that executes a PHP file with URL parameters?

Tags: php, curl, parameters

I'm trying to setup some cron jobs that run a PHP script every 3 hours. I have three jobs all hitting the same script, but with different parameters.

**Option 1**

I've learned that I can run the script right on the server like this:

`* */3 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite.com/public/index.php param=value > /dev/null 2>&1`

**Option 2**

I've also learned that I can `cURL` the URL like this:

`* */3 * * * curl http://myip/mysite.com/public/index.php?param=value > /dev/null 2>&1`

**Which is better?**

My script makes use of the `$_GET[]` variables, and I'd like to keep it that way, but apparently when you run a script from the command line, you need to use the `$argv` variable instead of `$_GET[]`. For that reason, the `cURL` method seems like the better approach.

However, I'm wondering if there is any difference between these two approaches, performance wise. Are there any downfalls of using `cURL` instead of just running the script locally on the server?

Or, alternatively, is there any way to use `$_GET[]` when running the script on the server (instead of `$argv`)?

Comment: Another consideration which isn't mentioned in the answers below is execution control.  Accessing the cronjob in Option 1 allows you to place the script outside of the web directory, meaning you do not need to worry about anyone else executing it.  Option 2 is leaving it open to others to reach it so you need to place in additional checks for how often the script performs its actions and possibly authentication logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use other privilegs such as root or something else, the first option is the way to go.
In many cases you have to change your dir before you execute your code
(cd /xyz/; php index.php param=value)

Otherwise is Option 2 the easiest way, because many variables are in Option 1 different and may cause an error.
Option 2 would be logged by apache/NGINX too and is like you access the URL as normal.

And at least, you have 2 different php.ini's:

Option 1 = CLI/php.ini (for example: there is a different timeout)

Option 2 = apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Performance-wise, the two should be identical, but the big difference is going to be in your php.ini. The curl version will be subject to whatever configuration is setup for viewing in a browser. Typically, this would be a cgi module via Apache, or it might be for php-fpm. At any rate, one of the most important configuration considerations is the time limit. You will likely have some sort of max_execution_time set for browsers (which curl falls under), but the cgi is hard-coded to zero, which means no timeouts.

If the script won't ever reach a timeout, then it probably doesn't matter and you can use option #2, but if it is long-running, then I would try to adapt it to read arguments and run from the cli using option #1.